# Jquery URI Anchor

Tags: jquery, uri

I have to use URI ANCHOR (https://github.com/mmikowski/urianchor) for a school's project and I am struggling with understanding how to use it. My webpage is a SPA and has a simple form to submit a project with title and description which then get's converted to a project's object which in turn gets added to an Array of projects, from which a table of projects is created.

I think I understand how to set the URI using the $.uriAnchor.setAnchor() method, however how do I update state after when the user goes back? Do I log those with $.uriAnchor.makeAnchorMap() or ? I know my question isn't really clear and I am not submitting any code but that's because I cannot understand how to use the plugin. Any tips or external online reading? I have tried googling for example solutions and tutorials but I couldn't find any. Thanks for the help in advance. :))

Answer (score 0):

When the Back button is clicked, the browser navigates to the previous url.  Your code gets the event using

```
        $(window)
        .bind( 'hashchange', onHashchange )  /* onHashChange is the event handler */
        .trigger('hashchange');
```

Complete documentation is in [github](https://github.com/mmikowski/urianchor).  The plugin author has a good overview in [his book](http://www.manning.com/mikowski/).